# BEM Naming Convention

Tags: naming-conventions, bem

I have just started to use BEM as my naming convention for classes and am starting to get to grips with it, but I have a question I would like to try and understand better.

I have the following block...

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="picturefill">
         <img class="picturefill__img" src="images/test.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="overlay__content overlay__content--bottom-left">
         <h2 class="overlay__title">About</h2>
         <a class="overlay__link" href="#">learn more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to make both the h2 and link white, which is easy enough, but I also have another type of block that exists outside the overlay where I would like a h2 to be white... what is the best way to go about this?

Do I create the CSS as follows...

```
.overlay__title,
.overlay__text{
    color: white;
}

.otherBlock__title{
    color: white;
}
```

Or is there a better way to do this? Can i create a utility class to create white elements?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure as I've never seen your design, but what I'd do is create one universal block called, let's say, `article` with optional modifier `overlay`. So the whole picture would be like this:

```
<div class="article">
    <div class="picturefill">
         <img class="picturefill__img" src="images/test.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="article__content article__content--bottom-left">
         <h2 class="article__title">About</h2>
         <a class="article__link" href="#">learn more</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="article article--overlay">
    <div class="picturefill">
         <img class="picturefill__img" src="images/test.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="article__content article__content--bottom-left">
         <h2 class="article__title">About</h2>
         <a class="article__link" href="#">learn more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And as so you may apply styles this way:

```
.article__title {
    color: white;
}

.article-overlay article__title {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to make both the h2 and link white, which is easy enough, but I also have another type of block that exists outside the overlay where I would like a h2 to be white... what is the best way to go about this?

For your specific case, it sounds like the best way to write the code would be:

```
// in overlay.css/.less/.scss/etc...
.overlay__title,
.overlay__text{
    color: white;
}

// in otherBlock.css/.less/.scss/etc...
.otherBlock__title{
    color: white;
}
```

Which looks oddly familiar.

To explain why, lets take a step away from CSS and look at how other programming languages work.

---

Imagine you have an object in an OOP language, such as C#, and that object is supposed to represent a book. The book object will probably need a `title` (e.x. Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy):

```
class Book {
  string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Now imagine that you now need to create an object that represents a person. The person object will *also* need a `title` (e.x. Dr.):

```
class Person {
  string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Between these two classes there is no inheritance structure. This means that there will be *some* code that needs to get rewritten, despite looking similar.

---

Going back to CSS, these two blocks *happen* to have some similar styles. You haven't described any sort of relation between the two that they should leverage for code reuse, so simply duplicate the styles.

If you use a preprocessor, you may find that it's useful to use variables—particularly for colors—and mixins—particularly for chunks of reusable styles—to reduce the amount of code you actually write, but in the end the CSS will be moderately repetitious.

This is fine. If your CSS gets served gzipped, then duplication will compress quite well.

---

...but what about other cases?

If you find that you're constantly overriding a particular set of styles (`.body__text`, `.content__text`, `.description__text`) and they all refer to the same element (e.x. `<p>`), then consider updating your default styles for that element to reduce the amount of CSS you're using to override the element.

If you find that you're constantly rebuilding the same particular structure *within* existing blocks, you may need to create a new block. For example:

```
<div class="article">
  <time class="article__timestamp">
    <span class="article__date">...</span>
    <span class="article__time">...</span>
  </time>
  ...
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="post">
  <time class="post__timestamp">
    <span class="post__date">...</span>
    <span class="post__time">...</span>
  </time>
  ...
</div>
```

might be refactored to:

```
<div class="article">
  <time class="timestamp">
    <span class="timestamp__date">...</span>
    <span class="timestamp__time">...</span>
  </time>
  ...
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="post">
  <time class="timestamp">
    <span class="timestamp__date">...</span>
    <span class="timestamp__time">...</span>
  </time>
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, BEM is just a methodology. You can do all you like. :) So, if your header and link always white for this component, store it in component css declaration. If it is a local matter, then create something like helpers.css, where you'll store rules like:

```
.white-text { color: white; }
.point { cursor: pointer; }
.text-center { text-align: center; }
```

This is 100% ok solution.

**UPDATE**

Just mentioned 2 minuses to my answer. Can't imagine, that someone can negate
methodology answer. :D

What I wanted to tell the author, that it's a really good decision to store commonly repeated rules in separated self explained selectors. For example, like bootstrap doing it.